# How to burn one's bridges in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom

If you leave a situation or a job in a way that makes you unwelcome to return ever again, you can be said to burn your bridges in English.
Is there an idiom in classical Latin for irrevocably destroying one's earlier relations?
Can you provide a classical use example?
The English phrase could be translated as *pontes suos exurere*, but I have never seen anything like it in use.

Comment: The same exact phrase as in English is attested in Italian, so I wouldn't totally exclude your tentative translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. I don't know of any corresponding idioms in Latin, but in general Latin is a pretty concrete language, shunning metaphor when it can, so my suspicion is that the way to say this is going to turn out to be rather prosaic.

Translated from metaphor, "burn your bridges" means something like "break connections of goodwill." In looking for less fanciful expressions that mean the same thing I find for example in Virgil's *Georgic IV*

> rege incolumi mens omnibus una est;
>   amisso **rupere fidem**, constructaque mella
>   diripuere ipsae et **cratis solvere favorum**.

And in Cicero's *De Amicitia* 85

> Nam implicati ultro et citro vel usu diuturno vel etiam officiis repente in medio cursu **amicitias** exorta aliqua offensione **disrumpimus**.

If I had to bet, I'd say it's going to be something boring like that, alas.

Comment: Thanks! I will wait to see if others have ideas to offer before accepting an answer, but this is excellent. Is your *Georgics* an intentional English plural of a Latin word or a typo?

Comment: The latter! It no longer exists!